# Regular expression with variable number of groups?

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to create a regular expression with a variable number of groups?

After running this for instance...

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ab([cd])*ef");
Matcher m = p.matcher("abcddcef");
m.matches();
```

... I would like to have something like

- `m.group(1)` = `"c"`
- `m.group(2)` = `"d"`
- `m.group(3)` = `"d"`
- `m.group(4)` = `"c"`.

---

(Background: I'm parsing some lines of data, and one of the "fields" is repeating. I would like to avoid a `matcher.find` loop for these fields.)

---

As pointed out by @Tim Pietzcker in the comments, [perl6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522302/perl-6-capturing-repeating-matching-groups-separately) and [.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx) have this feature.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#cg), Java regular expressions can't do this:

> The captured input associated with a
>   group is always the subsequence that
>   the group **most recently** matched. If a
>   group is evaluated a second time
>   because of quantification then its
>   previously-captured value, if any,
>   will be retained if the second
>   evaluation fails. Matching the string
>   "aba" against the expression (a(b)?)+,
>   for example, leaves group two set to
>   "b". All captured input is discarded
>   at the beginning of each match.

(emphasis added)

Answer (score 5):

You can use split to get the fields you need into an array and loop through that.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)

Answer (score 4):

I have not used java regex, but for many languages the answer is: No.

Capturing groups seem to be created when the regex is parsed, and filled when it matches the string. The expression `(a)|(b)(c)` has three capturing groups, only if either one, or two of them can be filled. `(a)*` has just one group, the parser leaves the last match in the group after matching.

Comment: .NET has [captures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures.aspx), so you can access individual matches of a repeated subgroup.

Comment: @Tim, ah, look at that. That's precisely what I'm after (but in Java).

Answer (score 2):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("ab(?:(c)|(d))*ef");
Matcher m = p.matcher("abcdef");
m.matches();
```

should do what you want.

EDIT:

@aioobe, I understand now.  You want to be able to do something like the grammar

```
A    ::== <Foo> <Bars> <Baz>
Foo  ::== "foo"
Baz  ::== "baz"
Bars ::== <Bar> <Bars>
        | ε
Bar  ::== "A"
        | "B"
```

and pull out all the individual matches of `Bar`.

No, there is no way to do that using `java.util.regex`.  You can recurse and use a regex on the match of `Bars` or use a parser generator like ANTLR and attach a side-effect to `Bar`.

Comment: Uhm, that's not a variable number of groups. That's always two groups. Perhaps I simplified my example a bit *too* much. (Clarified question.)

Comment: @aioobe, I edited this post to address your clarified question.

Answer (score 0):

I would think that backtracking inhibits this behavior, and say the effect of `/([\S\s])/` in its grouping accumulative state on something like the Bible. Even if it can be done, the output is unknowable as the groups will lose positional meaning. Its better to do a separate regex on like kind in a global sense and have it deposited into an array.

Answer (score 0):

I have just had the very similar problem, and managed to do "variable number of groups" but a combination of a while loop and resetting the matcher.

```
    int i=0;
    String m1=null, m2=null;

    while(matcher.find(i) && (m1=matcher.group(1))!=null && (m2=matcher.group(2))!=null)
    {
        // do work on two found groups
        i=matcher.end();
    }
```

But this is for my problem (with two repeating

```
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<=^ab[cd]{0,100})[cd](?=[cd]{0,100}ef$)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abcddcef")
    int i=0;
    String res=null;

    while(matcher.find(i) && (res=matcher.group())!=null)
    {
        System.out.println(res);
        i=matcher.end();
    }
```

You lose the ability to specify arbitrary length of repetition with `*` or `+` because look-ahead and look-behind must be of the predictable length.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a reasonable max number of matching groups you would encounter:

```
"ab([cd])?([cd])?([cd])?([cd])?([cd])?([cd])?([cd])?([cd])?ef"
```

This example will work for 0 - 8 matches. I admit this is ugly and not humanly readable.

Comment: `"ab" + "([cd])?".repeat(8) + "ef"` is slightly nicer.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to avoid a matcher.find loop for these fields.

As stated in other answers, that cannot be avoided. For completeness, here is how to do it using a second `Pattern` to go over the individual matches. Note the position of the `*` being inside the round brackets rather than after.

```java
Pattern subPattern = Pattern.compile("[cd]");
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("ab(" + subPattern.pattern() + "*)ef"); // DRY, but probably safer ways to do it for the case that subPattern needs to be changed.
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("abccdcddef is great and all, but have you heard about abef and abddcef?");
List<String> letterSequence = new ArrayList<>();
while (matcher.find()) {
    String letters = matcher.group(1);
    Matcher subMatcher = subPattern.matcher(letters);
    while (subMatcher.find()) {
        String letter = subMatcher.group();
        letterSequence.add(letter);
    }
}
System.out.println(letterSequence);
```

Output:

> [c, c, d, c, d, d, d, d, c]

Comment: This looks a bit broken. What if `subPattern` is `abc` then the `*` would only apply to `c`. You probably want to add a couple of braces.

Comment: There is an argument to be had about what a programmer changing `subPattern` should be expected to check, yes. I added a comment to the line. Not sure if there's a simple beats-all solution here. An extra abstraction to decouple both patterns seems verbose as it stands.