# RegEx to read multiple parameters of unknown multiplicity

Tags: java, regex

I'm a little stuck at a regular expression. Consider following code:

```
    String regFlagMulti = "^(\\[([\\w=]*?)\\])*?$";
    String flagMulti = "[TestFlag=1000][TestFlagSecond=1000]";
    Matcher mFlagMulti = Pattern.compile(regFlagMulti).matcher(flagMulti);

    if(mFlagMulti.matches()){
        for(int i = 0; i <= mFlagMulti.groupCount(); i++){
            System.out.println(mFlagMulti.group(i));
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("MultiFlag didn't match!");
    }
```

What I want is a regular pattern that gives me the text inside the **[ ]**; each one in a group of the resulting Matcher object.

**Important: I don't know how many [ ] expressions are inside the input string!**

For the code above it outputs:

```
[TestFlag=1000][TestFlagSecond=1000]
[TestFlagSecond=1000]
TestFlagSecond=1000
```

I can't get the regular Pattern to work. Anyone an idea?

Comment: This is not on point, but instead of `([\\w=]*?)`, perhaps `([^\\]]*)` would do as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ***What i want is a regular pattern that gives me the text inside the [ ]; each one in a group of the resulting Matcher object.***

Unfortunately this can't be done with the Java regex engine. See my (similar) question over here:

- [Regular expression with variable number of groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups)

---

This group:

```
(\\[([\\w=]*?)\\])*
\________________/
```

is group number 1 and will always contain *the last match* for that group.

---

Here's a suggestion for a solution, that also fetches the key/vals:

```
String regFlagMulti = "(\\[(\\w*?)=(.*?)\\])";
String flagMulti = "[TestFlag=1000][TestFlagSecond=1000]";
Matcher mFlagMulti = Pattern.compile(regFlagMulti).matcher(flagMulti);

while (mFlagMulti.find()) {
    System.out.println("String: " + mFlagMulti.group(1));
    System.out.println("   key: " + mFlagMulti.group(2));
    System.out.println("   val: " + mFlagMulti.group(3));
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

```
String: [TestFlag=1000]
   key: TestFlag
   val: 1000

String: [TestFlagSecond=1000]
   key: TestFlagSecond
   val: 1000
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a pattern which matches a single item in the string and use `Matcher.find()` to iterate over the whole String.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following:

```
String regFlagMulti = "\\[(\\w+=.*?)\\]";
String flagMulti = "[TestFlag=1000][TestFlagSecond=1000]";
Matcher mFlagMulti = Pattern.compile(regFlagMulti).matcher(flagMulti);
while(mFlagMulti.find()){
    System.out.println(mFlagMulti.group(1));
}
```

**Output:**

```
TestFlag=1000
TestFlagSecond=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron correctly pointed out, use one group (they are static to the pattern, repetitions are not added as additional groups) and call `find`.

The pattern to use could be like this: `\G\[([^\]]*)\](?=\[|$)`

Group 1 will then contain the text inside the `[]`.

*Notes:*

`\G` continues the match where the last match ended

`(?=` is a positive lookahead to make sure that the end of the pattern is as expected (e.g. either the end of the string, or the next `[`).