# I can't get the first group of regex pattern in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to get the first group of a regex pattern.
I got this string from a lyric text:

```
[01:34][01:36]Blablablahh nanana
```

I'm this regex pattern to extract [01:34],[03:36] and the text.

```
Pattern timeLine = Pattern.compile("(\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])+(.*)");
```

But when I try to extract the first group [01:34] using group(1) it returns [03:36]

is there something wrong in the regex pattern?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6939587/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5018487/139010.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is here

```
Pattern.compile("(\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])+(.*)");
                                      ^
```

This part of your pattern `(\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])+` will match `[01:34][01:36]` because of `+` (which is greedy), but your group 1 can contain only one of `[dd:dd]` so it will store the last match found.

If you want to find only `[01:34]` you can correct your pattern by removing `+`. But you can also create simpler pattern

```
Pattern.compile("^\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\]");
```

and use it with `group(0)` which is also called by `group()`.

```
Pattern timeLine = Pattern.compile("^\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\]");
Matcher m = timeLine.matcher("[01:34][01:36]Blablablahh nanana");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group()); // prints [01:34]
}
```

---

In case you want to extract both `[01:34][01:36]` you can just add another parenthesis to your current regex like

```
Pattern.compile("((\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])+)(.*)");
```

This way entire match of `(\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])+` will be in group 1.

You can also achieve it by removing `(.*)` from your original pattern and reading group 0.

Answer (score 1):

I thin you are confused by the repeating match `(\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])+` which returns just the last match as the group value. Try the following and see if it makes more sense to you:

```
    String s = "[01:34][01:36]Blablablahh nanana";
    Pattern timeLine = Pattern.compile("(\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])(\\[\\d\\d:\\d\\d\\])(.+)");
    Matcher m = timeLine.matcher(s);
    if (m.matches()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++) {
            System.out.printf("    Group %d -> %s\n", i, m.group(i)); // prints [01:36]
        }
    }
```

which for me returns:

```
Group 1 -> [01:34]
Group 2 -> [01:36]
Group 3 -> Blablablahh nanana
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply grab the first part using a character class:

```
String timings = str.replaceAll("([\\[\\]\\d:]+).*", "$1");
```

And similarly the text:

```
String text = str.replaceAll("[\\[\\]\\d:]+", "");
```

Comment: I think in your first regex you wanted to use `).*` at the end :). Anyway +1 for one-liner.

Comment: @Pshemo yes, you're right. thanks for fixing it up :) (and +1 for you too - nice explanation)