# Java regex to parse any number of Markdown-style links

Tags: java, regex, markdown

I'm trying to parse a string for any occurrences of markdown style links, i.e. `[text](link)`. I'm able to get the first of the links in a string, but if I have multiple links I can't access the rest. Here is what I've tried, you can run it on [ideone](http://ideone.com/BtySKB):

```
Pattern p;
try {
    p = Pattern.compile("[^\\[]*\\[(?<text>[^\\]]*)\\]\\((?<link>[^\\)]*)\\)(?:.*)");
} catch (PatternSyntaxException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);
    throw(ex);
}
Matcher m1 = p.matcher("Hello");
Matcher m2 = p.matcher("Hello [world](ladies)");
Matcher m3 = p.matcher("Well, [this](that) has [two](too many) keys.");
System.out.println("m1 matches: " + m1.matches());  // false
System.out.println("m2 matches: " + m2.matches());  // true
System.out.println("m3 matches: " + m3.matches());  // true
System.out.println("m2 text: " + m2.group("text")); // world
System.out.println("m2 link: " + m2.group("link")); // ladies
System.out.println("m3 text: " + m3.group("text")); // this
System.out.println("m3 link: " + m3.group("link")); // that
System.out.println("m3 end: " + m3.end());          // 44 - I want 18
System.out.println("m3 count: " + m3.groupCount()); // 2 - I want 4
System.out.println("m3 find: " + m3.find());        // false - I want true
```

I know I can't have [repeating groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939526/java-regex-repeating-capturing-groups), but I figured [`find`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29) would work, however it does not work as I expected it to. How can I modify my approach so that I can parse each link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you go through the matches one by one and do the next match from an index after the previous match? You can use this regex:

```
\[(?<text>[^\]]*)\]\((?<link>[^\)]*)\)
```

The method `Find()` tries to find all matches even if the match is a substring of the entire string. Each call to find gets the next match. `Matches()` tries to match the entire string and fails if it doesn't match. Use something like this:

```
while (m.find()) {
    String s = m.group(1);
    // s now contains "BAR"
}
```

Comment: I tried a similar syntax, but `m3.matches()` was `false`, probably because of the trailing characters which aren't `)`. Any suggestions on how I can work around that?

Comment: I guess the issue with your above pattern is that (?:.*) causes the match to continue all the way to the end of the string. So you pass all other prospective matches in the way. I would use a pattern like I suggested and get all the matches from the string.

Comment: It's strange that matches is false. Find does give the results with the pattern used in answer. Test it here : http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/

Comment: `.matches()` is `false` with `"\\[(?<text>[^\\]]*)\\]\\((?<link>[^\\)]*)\\)"`. But `.find()` is `true`. I think I understand what I have to do but could you write up what to do in order to get each pair of groups so I can accept your answer?

Answer (score 0):

The regular expression I've used to match what you need (without groups) is `\[\w+\]\(.+\)`

It is just to show you it simple. Basically it does:

- Filter a square: `\[`
- Followed by any word char (at least 1): `\w+`
- Then the square: `\]`

This will look for these pattern `[blabla]`

Then the same with parenthesis...

- Filter a parenthesis: `\(`
- Followed by any char (at least 1): `.+`
- Then the parenthesis: `\)`

So it filters `(ble...ble...)`

Now if you want to store the matches on groups you can use additional parenthesis like this:

`(\[\w+\])(\(.+\))` in this way you can have stored the words and links.

Hope to help.

I've tried on regexplanet.com and it's working

Update: workaround `.*(\[\w+\])(\(.+\))*.*`

Comment: This suffers from the same problem that I had with Farhad's answer.

Comment: Can you try this workaround, I've update the post at the end since can't post it here

Comment: Right, but my problem is that I can only find the first `default` and first `key` groups.