# Java Regex Capturing Groups for {X}

Tags: java, regex, capturing-group

I have a regex with a character sequence. I want the sequences parts into groups.

```
Pattern e_1394Pattern = Pattern
        .compile("\\dR\\|\\d\\|(((([^\\|]))*\\|){11})");

String resultLine = "\4R|1|^^^02^Myo^1021406330|25.6^F|ng/mL||N||F||Administrator||20140318215839|";
```

This pattern works fine, but I need the groups of the following Part `(((([^\\|]))*\\|){11})`.
Is this possible using a short regex?

This is no option: `\\dR\\|\\d\\|((([^\\|]))*\\|) ((([^\\|]))*\\|) ((([^\\|]))*\\|) ((([^\\|]))*\\|)....`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java regex: Repeating capturing groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939526/java-regex-repeating-capturing-groups)

Comment: sorry, I think that is not the same... I want the repeated part of the regex '(ab){n}' in groups. the result of this is one group 'ab'

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your need, but how about:

You can repeat pattern with `(?1)` or `\g1` that will repeat the pattern used for group 1, depending on regex flavor.

In your case:

```
"\\dR\\|\\d\\|(((([^\\|]))*\\|){11})"
```

is the same as (removing superfluous grouping):

```
"\\dR\\|\\d\\|([^\\|]*\\|)(?1)(?1)(?1)(?1)(?1)(?1)(?1)(?1)(?1)(?1)"
```

Comment: Java doesn't support subroutine calls.  Not as of Java 8, anyway.

Comment: @AlanMoore: Too bad :( . I keep the answer for ones who deal with another language.