# How do i repeat regex

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
"(.+?)",.+?},\s.+?:\s
```

I would like to know if there is a way to repeat this regex, so i don't need to write it several times like this:

```
"(.+?)",.+?},\s.+?:\s"(.+?)",.+?},\s.+?:\s"(.+?)",.+?},\s.+?:\s
```

Comment: Just use string blocks to build the pattern dynamically.

Comment: Use the `/g` flag?

Comment: As @torazaburo say's, quantify the constructs within a cluster group `(?:"(.+?)",.+?},\s.+?:\s){3}` However, that means the single capture group will be overwritten 3 times, containing the final value of the 3rd quantified pass.

Comment: Suspiciously, you have quantifiers and a group in the regex, yet you still ask if there is a way to quantify that block 3 times. You'd think this is a question that would come up before one knew how to use groups and quantifiers, not the reverse..

Answer (score 31):

Put the regEx block in `()` and add `*` or `+`.

`*` 0 to any number of times.

`+` 1 to any number of times.

`{n}` 'n' times.

`{n,}` at-least 'n' times.

`(?: ... )` is called non-capturing group

Non-capturing parentheses group the regex so that you can apply regex operators, but do not capture anything.

Eg:

`[0-9]{1}` this means 1 digit(0-9)

`[0-9]+` this means at-least one digit(0-9).

`[0-9]*` no digits or any number of digits(0-9).

---

Since you wanted `"(.+?)",.+?},\s.+?:\s"(.+?)",.+?},\s.+?:\s"(.+?)",.+?},\s.+?:\s`,

you may do it like this : `("(.+?)",.+?},\s.+?:\s){3}`.

Comment: And if necessary use `(:` to avoid capturing.

Comment: The block could also be appended with `{3}` if the OP is looking for exactly 3 matches.

Comment: wouldn't that be `(?:` to avoid capturing?

Comment: @Nick yes, that was probably a typo by [tarozaburo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/663031/torazaburo)

Comment: @lurker yes, covered :)

Comment: You could also use the recursive option `(?R)?` at the end of your existing regex, if your engine supports it.

Comment: @JamesBuck Example : The regexes `a(?R)?z`, `a(?0)?z`, and `a\g<0>?z` all match one or more letters `a` followed by exactly the same number of letters `z`. [Reference link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/recurse.html)

Comment: This is not the same. Using a quantifier on a fragment will not create more captured groups. OP's regex has 3 captured groups, but this approach will only have 1 captured group.

Comment: @Bohemian A variable number of capturing groups may not be used, but we can specify the number of times it is to be repeated. Eg:`(RegEx){3}`   [Also check](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6939587/2142994)

Comment: @Ani, but the OP is capturing 3 separate parts of the input, which your approach can not do

Comment: @Bohemian No he wants to repeat the same regEx multiple times. `"I would like to know if there is a way to repeat this regex"`

Comment: @Ani no, he wants to create the larger regex as per his question by repeating a smaller regex, which can not be done due to there being 3 capturing groups in his desired final regex

Comment: Here, Bohemian is right, there are capturing groups. And that means the question is unclear and should be closed.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew He wanted that pattern shown without repeating the smaller pattern, I have added the solution to that in the answer above.

Comment: @Bohemian I think that is what he wanted as his question was very specific to "how to get this?"

Comment: @ani and your answer does NOT achieve his stated goal. Your regex is not the same. It's very simple

Comment: @wik I don't think the question is unclear because OP has posted the exact regex he wants to achieve.