# How to replace ' ' by '_' only if words are in capital letters?

Tags: regex, xml, powershell, parsing

I am parsing a string into XML with powershell:

> NODE IP 0.0.0.0  "APXPRD"

And I need to got:

> `<NODE_IP>0.0.0.0  "APXPRD"</NODE_IP>`

I try to use regexp, but cant catch how to replace ' ' to '_' only if it between words in all capital letters, any advice?

I Try like that regexp:

```
$textis = 'NODE IP 0.0.0.0  "APXPRD"'
$textnew = $textis.replace('/^\s*[A-Z]+(?:\s+[A-Z]+)/m', '_')
```

but that seems not work :/

Comment: Please provide more context. There's probably a better solution to the overall problem than fixing a regular expression for this particular case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can search for:

```
((?:^|\s)[A-Z]+)\s([A-Z]+(?:\s|$))
```

And replace it with:

```
$1_$2
```

This will look for a string with uppercase letters (`[A-Z]`) which are directly after a whitespace (`\s`) or the beginning of the string (`^`). Then, a whitespace is necessary in between and at the end, it matches again for a whitespace (`\s`) or the string end (`$`).

---

If you are using PowerShell to replace it, you need to do it like this (take care about this: the command of case-sensitive matching is `creplace` not just `replace`):

```
$textis = 'NODE IP 0.0.0.0 TEST String "APXPRD"'
$textnew = $textis -creplace '((?:^|\s)[A-Z]+)\s([A-Z]+(?:\s|$))','$1_$2'
```

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: $textnew = $textis.replace('[A-Z]+)\s([A-Z]+', '$1_$2') not work :/

Comment: You are missing the brackets... `$textnew = $textis.replace('([A-Z]+)\s([A-Z]+)', '$1_$2')` And maybe you need to escape the \ in `\s` too. So it would be `$textnew = $textis.replace('([A-Z]+)\\s([A-Z]+)', '$1_$2')`

Comment: thanks you are right about brackets, but still not working for me for some reasons, cant understand why.
PS C:\Windows\system32> $textis = 'NODE IP 0.0.0.0  "APXPRD"'

PS C:\Windows\system32> $textnew = $textis.replace('(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z])', '$1_$2')

PS C:\Windows\system32> $textnew
NODE IP 0.0.0.0  "APXPRD"

PS C:\Windows\system32> $textnew = $textis.replace('([A-Z]+)\\s([A-Z]+)', '$1_$2')

PS C:\Windows\system32> $textnew
NODE IP 0.0.0.0  "APXPRD"

Comment: @GorodeckijDimitrij If you are using PowerShell, you can use the `-replace` command. See the updated answer.

Comment: Could you plese help me a little with that - if its a line like "SEVERITY Warning" its also became "SEVERITY_Warning" but i want to avoid that, it should replace space only if second word all leters are capital. Is that posible?

Comment: You are right, that will match too, I'll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just got another case - hope you can help there as well, is that possible to replace space in that one: CONDITION TEXT SET? as for now its replace only CONDITION_TEXT SET
Thanks for you help, that regexp magic make my crazy :)

Comment: It is quite easy to write an expression for three words, but rather difficult if your trying to match `n` words (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6939587/3233827)). So, you would need a different regular expression for every number of words you want to match. If you only want to match 3 words, you would replace it with `$1_$2_$3`, which won't work anymore for two words (it would lead to `CONDITION__TEXT`). So, you would need to multiply replace it in decreasing number of words with a different pattern each.

Comment: ah, I was not understand $1_#2 stuff properly (beginner in powershell), now I got it! Thanks a lot again!

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z])
```

Will get you the spaces between capital letters.

Note the space in the middle. It's using lookbehind and lookahead

Comment: $textnew = $textis.replace('?<=[A-Z]) (?=[A-Z]', '_') not working - is that not correct way to use regex in replace perhaps?

Comment: @GorodeckijDimitrij You are missing the starting and ending brackets in your code snippet.

Comment: The brackets are important