# How To Match Repeating Sub-Patterns

Tags: java, regex

Let's say I have a string:

```
String sentence = "My nieces are Cara:8 Sarah:9 Tara:10";
```

And I would like to find all their respective names and ages with the following pattern matcher:

```
String regex = "My\\s+nieces\\s+are((\\s+(\\S+):(\\d+))*)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile;
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sentence);
```

I understand something like

```
matcher.find(0); // resets "pointer"
String niece = matcher.group(2);
String nieceName = matcher.group(3);
String nieceAge = matcher.group(4);
```

would give me my last niece (`" Tara:10"`, `"Tara"`, `"10"`,).

How would I collect all of my nieces instead of only the last, using only one regex/pattern?

I would like to avoid using split string.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6939587/1553851

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java regex: Repeating capturing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6939526/java-regex-repeating-capturing-groups)

Comment: Another idea is to [use the `\G` anchor](https://regex101.com/r/i0vPYF/1) to *continue where the previous match ended*, [see this demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##fZAxT8MwEIX3/Iqjk60KizJBqqpCDEyVkMqGGUxypC6xE9mXQgX97eGSuBILDPazz989@3lvDuZyX773vXVtEwj2XFAd2VoFrPBTbQwVOwzL7I/zR0OEwS@zrKhNjEAYKfvKANrutbYFRDLEcmhsCc5YD2JLwfrq@QVMqKJkcqABpjJE9IS@QFjBbHMEb7HAyCjCvQkmv4Etyy6/hadhu7iaLX93j28aWsU61/pBrC@0vpPfm6PWcT55DSu2k4MKrbdzmbOUc5mcUiBok67OFVU0rrU1ivESOdHjlP4IHMOpTbmpJs55mB/Zjx1bgHDqzfpSSJnSc4JjJHSq6Ui1nIVqz1AVmq4VC5lu@5e6PlOnbBinvv8B)

Comment: @bobblebubble Very cool. You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another idea is to use the [`\G` anchor](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-anchors.html#G) that matches where the previous match ended (or at start).

```
String regex = "(?:\\G(?!\\A)|My\\s+nieces\\s+are)\\s+(\\S+):(\\d+)";
```

- If `My\s+nieces\s+are` matches
- `\G` will chain matches from there
- `(?!\A)` neg. [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) prevents `\G` from matching at `\A` [start](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html#az)
- `\s+(\S+):(\d+)` using two [capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) for extraction

See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/i0vPYF/1) or a [Java demo at tio.run](https://tio.run/##fY9BT4QwEIXv/IpxT22IjetJIWZjPHgiMcGb9VBhhCItpB1Wie5vx7KwiZf10L7p9JuXN43aq8um/JgmbfrOETShIQbSrXBY4ZfIFBU1ujQ68/@kiNDZNIqKVnkPhJ6i7wigH95aXYAnRUH2nS7BKG2B5eS0rV5eQbnK80DONMDSBo@W0BYId7DJRrAaC/QBRXhQTiU3kAepk1t4np/bq036d/qYaR5lu0TKR7a7kPKe/2SjlD5evOYq2PFZmZR5zJMgZcxXp3VhMMFmXU4Unel1i2yx58IsDDuF5cvo8fqsAwnMiHdtS8b5ul6IOHpCI7qBRB/CUmsDVLlu6NmWrw7/Utcn6hDN5zBNvw)

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(sentence);

while (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
  System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

Comment: Thank you, both for the answer and the thorough explanation !

Answer (score 2):

You can't [iterate over repeating groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6939587/1553851), but you can match each group individually, calling `find()` in a loop to get the details of each one. If they need to be back-to-back, you can iteratively bound your matcher to the last index, like this:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("My\\s+nieces\\s+are").matcher(sentence);
if (matcher.find()) {
    int boundary = matcher.end();
    
    matcher = Pattern.compile("^\\s+(\\S+):(\\d+)").matcher(sentence);
    while (matcher.region(boundary, sentence.length()).find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        
        boundary = matcher.end();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but there should only be one regex/pattern. Will update my question to reflect this.