# Regular expressions: some groups missing

Tags: java, regex

I have following Java code:

```
String s2 = "SUM   12  32 42";
Pattern pat1 = Pattern.compile("(PROD)|(SUM)(\\s+(\\d+))+");
Matcher m = pat1.matcher(s2);
System.out.println(m.matches());
System.out.println(m.groupCount());
for (int i = 1; i <=  m.groupCount(); ++i) {
        System.out.println(m.group(i));
}
```

which produces:

```
true
4
null
SUM
 42
42
```

I wonder what's a `null` and why 12 and 32 are missing (I expected to find them amongst groups).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Group `X` from this part of your regex:

```
(\\s+(\\d+))+
|          |
+----------+--> X
```

will first match `12`, then `32` and finally `42`. Each time `X`'s value gets changed, and replaces the previous one. If you want *all* values, you'll need a `Pattern` & `Matcher.find()` approach:

```
String s = "SUM   12  32 42 PROD 1 2";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(PROD|SUM)((\\s+\\d+)+)").matcher(s);
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Matched : " + m.group(1));
    Matcher values = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher(m.group(2));
    while(values.find()) {
        System.out.println("        : " + values.group());
    }
}
```

which will print:

```
Matched : SUM
        : 12
        : 32
        : 42
Matched : PROD
        : 1
        : 2
```

And you see a `null` printed because in group 1, there's `PROD`, which you didn't match.

Answer (score 5):

A repeated group will contain the match of the *last* substring matching the expression for the group.

It would be nice if the regexp engine would give back *all* substrings that matched a group. Unfortunately this is not supported:

- [Regular expression with variable number of groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups)

Furthermore groups are a static and numbered like this:

```
                    0
          _______________________
         /                       \
         (PROD)|(SUM)(\\s+(\\d+))+
         \____/ \___/|    \____/| 
           1      2  |       4  |
                      \________/ 
                           3
```

Answer (score -1):

```
I wonder what's a null
```

Capturing groups are indexed from left to right, starting at one. Group zero denotes the entire pattern, so the expression m.group(0) is equivalent to m.group().

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29

the string given does not matches the entire pattern.

Comment: This information is irrelevant to my null, because it is produced by m.group(1) not by m.group(0).