# Catching an item in a repeating element

Tags: regex

I want to transform this:

```
Public [Function|Sub] XXXX(ByVal param1 As aaaa, ByVal param2 AS bbbb) As cccc
```

Into this:

```
Log("Method XXXX:", "param1", param1, "param2", param2)
```

The number of parameters is variable.

Can I do it in pure regexp, and if so, how can I do it ?
I will use a simple tool like this: http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ to do it manually for each method.

I am here:

```
Public (Function|Sub) ([\w\d_]+)\((ByVal .* As .*)*\)( As [\w]+)?
Log("Method $2:", $3)
```

Which gives me this:

```
Log("Method XXXX:", ByVal param1 As aaaa, ByVal param2 AS bbbb)
```

It's a small step forward, but not really a big one...

The problem being, I don't know if (and how) it's possible to catch a repeating sub-item. Other questions point to it not being possible ?

I need to do it in pure regexp, not in code. Otherwise, I will use copypasta, but I would love to maximize the automation.

Thanks !

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups

Comment: is the number of param defined? And what language will you use? (cause there is different regex flavour)

Comment: I put more precisions in my question: the number of parameters is variable, and I use a tool (like online, or Notepad++ or such). I don't want to write code for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Search

```
/^[^\]]*[\]] ([\w\d_]+)\(ByVal ([^ ]*) As ([^,]*), ByVal ([^ ]*) As ([^,]*)\)( As [\w]+)/gi
```

Replace (with variable value)

```
Log("Method $2:", $3, "$4", $5)
```

OR (with variable name)

```
Log("Method $2:", $2, "$4", $4)
```

Example:
http://regexr.com?357f4

**EDIT**

For looping, you could try 3 regular expressions.  First would simply change your beginning:

Search

```
/^[^\]]*[\]] ([\w\d_]+)/gi
```

Replace

```
Log("Method $1:",
```

Example: http://regexr.com?357fp

Then you would do the "looping", though not really looping.

Search

```
/\({0,1}ByVal ([^ ]*) As([^,\)]*[\)]{0,1})/gi
```

Replace

```
"$1:", $2
```

Example: http://regexr.com?357g2

Then you remove the ending

Search

```
/\).*/gi
```

Replace

```
)
```

Example: http://regexr.com?357g5

Comment: Thanks, but the number of parameters can vary. That's the real problem.

Comment: @thomasbtv Updated answer.  Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, but it means I must use several regexes to do what I want. I wanted to use only one. I feel it's not possible.