# Trying to get multiple matches out of a string with REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL()

Tags: java, regex, apache-pig

I have a string field error_cd with the value "cntrlb cntrlb asdv cntrlb asvd cntrla cntrlb cntrlb"

Within PIG, I'm trying to use `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL(error_cd, '.*(cntrl[a-b]).*')` to get back a tuple of `(cntrlb,cntrlb,cntrlb,cntrla,cntrlb)` or just `(cntrl,cntrl,...,cntrl)`. Instead, I'm getting back just one match `(cntrl)`.

Anybody know how to return all of the matches, as the function name implies?

Answer (score 1):

`REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL` is for extracting all of the capturing groups in a regular expression. It does not apply a single regular expression multiple times.  [This document](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.1/func.html#regex-extract-all) is somewhat out of date, but it still is accurate for `REGEX_EXTRACT_ALL`.

There is no regular expression that can capture an arbitrary number of groups. (See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups).)  If you had a known limit of times your `cntrl` string could occur, you could design a big ugly regex to capture them all, but it sounds like you'd be better off using `TOKENIZE` and then treating each word in your string individually.