# Repeating groups regex url path, node.js

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I am trying to extract express route named parameters with regex.

So, for example:

```
www.test.com/something/:var/else/:var2
```

I am trying with this regex:

```
.*\/?([:]+\w+)+
```

but I am getting only last matched group.

Does anyone knows how to match both `:var` and `:var2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is that `.*` is [greedy](https://www.google.com/search?q=regex+greedy+possessive+reluctant), and will therefore bypass all matches until the final one is found. This means that the first `:var` is bypassed.

However, as you are searching for a [variable number of capture groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups) (with thanks to @MichaelTang), I recommend using two regexes in sequence. First, use

```
^(?:.*?\/?\:\w+)+$
```

to detect *which lines contain colon-elements*...

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/c5mnKQe-1fkQL8EU)

...and then search that line repeatedly for, simply

```
\/:(\w+)
```

This places the text post-colon into capture group one.

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/Cl81tS6wmsfpK2xx)

Comment: Thank you on your answer. But still if I run ``> var res = 'www.test.com/something/:var/else/:var2'.match(/.*?\/?([:]+\w+)+/);`` in node.js, I am getting only one group, not both :/.

Comment: It is not clear then, from your question, exactly what your goal is. Are you trying to capture `:var` and also `:var2`? And is the format of every line exactly the same? Meaning always two colon-elements? Never three or one? Some more realistic and more examples input and expected output would be most helpful, if you want better answers.

Comment: Yes, I need to capture :var and :var2 (and others if exist with pattern like /:something). I will update my question.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to have a [variable number of capture groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups)... Perhaps it might be best to just programmatically build your Regex string with `new Regex(str)` based on the number of `:` chars in your path?

Comment: Okay, thank you @MichaelTang. I didn't catch that part of his comment-response until you mentioned it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can match both of them:

```
www.test.com/something/:var/else/:var2'.match(/\:(\w+)/g)
```

```
[":var", ":var2"]
```