# Javascript regex: dynamic capture group

Tags: javascript, regex, capture-group

I'm trying to wrap my mind around regex for the first time.

For the string

```
I want you to MATCH THIS, you bastard regex, but also MATCH X THIS and yeah,
MATCH X X X THIS too.
```

Basically, a starting pattern, an end pattern and an arbitrary number of a pattern inbetween.

So I'd like a `myregex.exec string` to successively return

```
["MATCH", "THIS"]
["MATCH", "X", "THIS"]
["MATCH", "X", "X", "X", "THIS"]
```

I've tried variations of this

```
/(MATCH)\s+(X)?\s+(THIS)/
```

but no cigar...

Comment: So do you want to match all the white space delimitted upper case words?

Comment: This is partially answered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups - see Tim Picker's comment.

Short answer: in some flavours of Regex you can ask for multiple captures of the same group. But not in javascript.

Comment: Having said that - you can group all of it in one group and then split.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting the `\s+` into the optional group with `*`:

```
/(MATCH)\s+(?:(X)\s)*(THIS)/g
```

Note the `g` modifier to get all matches.

Comment: `(?:(X))` would never have done that. A capture group in a non-capture group ... weird. Doesn't work for MATCH X X X THIS, but apparently that don't work in JavaScript...

Comment: Will match multiple `X`s but will only ever return a single `X` as a capture group using `RegExp.exec()` - and for `MATCH THIS` it will return an empty capture group for the `X`s.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the regular expression to match the entire expression:

```
/MATCH\s+(?:X\s+)*THIS/g
```

To get it into an array of terms/words you can then use `String.split()` like this:

```js
var out = document.getElementById( "out" );

function parse( string ){
  var re = /MATCH\s+(?:X\s+)*THIS/g;
  var matches = (string.match( re ) || [])
                  .map( function(m){ return m.split( /\s+/ ); } );
  out.innerHTML = JSON.stringify( matches );
}

parse( document.getElementById( "in" ).value );
```

```css
textarea { width: 100%; }
```

```html
<textarea id="in" onchange="parse( this.value )">I want you to MATCH THIS, you bad regex, but also MATCH X THIS and yeah, MATCH X X X THIS too.</textarea>
<p id="out"/>
```