# Extracting parameters from a method call using REGEX in JAVA

Tags: java, regex

I have this REGEX:

```
([A-Za-z]+[\w_]*)\s*\(([[A-Za-z]+[\w_]*\s,?]*)
```

This REGEX is supposed to find strings like this:

```
foo(param1,param2,param3......)
```

Where the first group is the name (it must start with a letter), after that comes the second group which I am not sure about. The problem is that I do not know how many parameters I will receive. The second part is suppose to find a concatenation of zero or more parameters, all in the same format [`A-Za-z]+[\w_]`. I tried adding a `[]` around it and a `*` at the end. How will I be able to match and extract all the parameters into a array list? Is it even a correct REGEX syntax?

Comment: will there be parameters in which function is passed?

Comment: Why are you using a regex, and not a java parsing library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)\s*\(\s*([a-zA-Z0-9_$]+(?:\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)*)\s*\)
```

- In the part `([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)`

  - `[a-zA-Z]` is for the first charcater - which has to be a letter.
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_$]*` is for the rest of the name - which may include letters, numbers, `_` or `$`.
- `\s*` for spaces. (Some people put them.)
- `\(` for `(`.
- `\s*` is again for spaces.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9_$]+` is for the first parameter.
- `(?:\s*,\s*[a-zA-Z0-9_$]+)*` is for the rest of the parameters.

  - `\s*` is again for spaces.
  - `,` is for matching `,`
  - `\s*` is again for spaces.
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9_$]+` is for parameter names.
  - The beginning `(?:` and `)*` finds as many extra parameters as it can.
- `\s*` is again for spaces.
- `\)` is for the closing bracket.

Comment: Your answer is perfect. Can you tell what if the arguments are surrounded by single qoute. For Example :    method('arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3')                                                          
Match group should return arg1 arg2 arg3.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regex

```
([A-Za-z]\w*)\s*\(\s*[A-Za-z]\w*\s+[A-Za-z]\w*\s*(?:,\s*[A-Za-z]\w*\s+[A-Za-z]\w*\s*)*\)
                 <----------------------------2nd part--------------------------------->
```

*Regex Breakdown* (for 2nd part)

```
\( #Match ( literally
  \s* #Match the spaces after (
  [A-Za-z]\w* #Match return type like int, float, String
  \s+ #Match at least one space
  [A-Za-z]\w* #Match variable names
  \s* #Match if there are any spaces
    (?:
      , #Match , literally
      \s* #Match spaces
       [A-Za-z]\w* #Match return type like int, float, String
       \s+ #Match at least one space
       [A-Za-z]\w* #Match variable names
       \s* #Match any number of spaces
    )* #Repeat this 0 or more times
\) #Match ) literally
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eH7hE7/2)**

Above will require at least one parameter. If you don't want any parameter, you can use

```
([A-Za-z]\w*)\s*\((?:\s*[A-Za-z]\w*\s+[A-Za-z]\w*\s*(?:,\s*[A-Za-z]\w*\s+[A-Za-z]\w*\s*)*)?\s*\)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5018487/regular-expression-with-variable-number-of-groups)).

The best you can do is come up with a regexp(*) that will catch all the parameters in one group, and then split that with further code.

(*) something like (unchecked):

```
([A-Za-z]+[\w_]*(\s*,\s*[A-Za-z]+[\w_]*)*)
```

Note that if this is supposed to handle real Java code, parameters can be string and number literals, function/method calls or complete expressions, so a single regexp won't cut it anyway...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you'd want to write `(XXX)*` to say that the `XXX` can repeat zero or more times, NOT `[XXX]*'.

That being said, however, you can't actually write a single regex to do what you have in mind; regexes aren't that powerful.  If you are especially keen to work with regexes for some reason, have a look at `java.util.regex.Matcher` or `java.util.Scanner`.  For a quick-and-dirty solution, just use `String.indexOf` to locate the delimiters and `String.substring` to extract the words from between them.